# SwipeRefresh + right/left ViewPager sliding

Tags: android

On one of the pages in my app I'm using SwipeRefresh, scrollView and ViewPager together. That means it can pretty much be "dragged" in any direction.

This is causing some interactive issues.

Everything is working fine, but doing a small change of direction while for example sliding to the left to open the next fragment in the ViewPager makes it "drop" the slide and instead start swipeRefresh.

So for a perfect viewPager slide your finger needs to go in a perfect 90 angle and needs to be kept that way all the way through the slide.

So the question :

Is there a way to know if user is sliding left in the viewPager, and then stop the possibility of triggering the swipeRefresh while this is occouring ?

**EDIT:**

Fixed by using addOnPageChangeListener to the viewPager. Suggested by Max Aves in the answer.

I did it like this:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    if(state == 0){
       swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
       swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide all the code of whatever you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ViewPager scroll listener: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener

So you can check is your viewpager scroll is used. So inside OnPageChangeListener you can operate with flags for other gestures.

> Note that OnPageChangeListener can receive next events:
>   SCROLL_STATE_IDLE 
>   SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING
>   SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out and come back to you